# Emmet VIM trigger key remap issue

Tags: vim, dictionary, emmet

I just installed Emmet VIM plugin which looks very interesting.  The "trigger key combination" to activate the Emmet plugin functionality is not the best it could be.  Therefore I am trying to remap it in my vimrc file.  I have successfully done that to remap the Escape key as follows:

```
inoremap ;; <ESC>
```

This allows me to type the semi-colon character ";" in rapid succession to get out of the insert mode and get in the normal mode.  However it does not work when I try to remap the Emmet trigger key which is  , (to be read as Control key and "y" key, followed by the "," key).  I have tried the following combinations:

```
inoremap hh <C-y> ,
inoremap hh <C-y>,
inoremap hh <C-y,>
```

As you can see above, I am trying to map "hh" key combination to the Emmet VIM's trigger keys.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Bharat

Comment: `inoremap ;; <ESC>` – careful with mappings like that, it could harm your pinky, smth like `jj` could be a better option

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`inoremap` means that if there is a mapping (such as to `,`) it will not be followed via the key combination for the mapping.  You probably want `imap`

```
imap hh <C-y>,
```

Answer (score 15):

I use that:

```
let g:user_emmet_leader_key=','
```

So ',,' triggers Emmet.

Comment: Great idea! Thanks!

Comment: Wow, Nice Idea. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Emmet VIM provides a way to redefine it:

```
let g:user_emmet_leader_key='hh'
```

Found on the README: https://github.com/mattn/emmet-vim/#redefine-trigger-key

Comment: doesn't work for my situation where I remapped with <Tab><CR>

Answer (score 1):

The smarter way is to use [Expression Mappings](http://bling.github.io/blog/2013/07/21/smart-tab-expansions-in-vim-with-expression-mappings), like:

```
au FileType html imap <buffer><expr><tab> <sid>zen_html_tab()
```

Comment: Context mapping is another awesomeness I didn't knew about. Thanks for the link, it explains it well.